# Mapping ID values using SQL

Tags: sql-server, identity, uniqueidentifier

Assume you have 2 DB with matching table structures in both.
For example,

```
D1.T1(ID, VAL) = D2.T1(ID,VAL)
D1.T2(ID, NAME,FID) = D2.T2(ID, NAME,FID)
```

Where `D1.T2.FID = D1.T1.ID`

Now I want to copy rows from D1 to D2. But ID values changes during the insert into D2 (not because I can't force insert the same ID by using IDENTITY_INSERT, its because the same ID exist in D2.T1 for some other values).

Now I need to update the D2.T2 with the new identity values. How can this be done, without altering tables (to persist the old_id value in D2.T1 and doing an update later on on D2.T2 by comparing the old id value)?

To give a hint of the tables structure see below.

D1.T1

```
ID, VAL
4934, A
4936, B
5011, C
```

D1.T2

```
ID, NAME, FKID
2478, I, 4934
2479, II, 4936
2481, III, 5011
```

D2.T1

```
ID, VAL
7813, A
7817, B
7819, C
```

D2.T2

```
ID, NAME, FKID
3416, I, 7813
3417, II, 7817
3419, III, 7819
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for example, we now come across a

```
   D1.T1  of 7813, D
```

and then discover that 7813 already exists in D2.T1??

"But ID values change during the insert into D2"

> > > What does it change to?  say 9876 ??  So now D2.T1 would be 9876, D

Well, lets go on and try to copy

```
   D1.T2  of  2482, IIII, 7813
```

BUT WAIT >> How do we know if this 7813 refers to 7813, A  or 7813, D

We don't know, We cannot determine if we need to keep 7813 or change to 9876.

Ergo, we need more information that resides in the table, e.g. another column.